# Meteor: Publish & Subscribe. How to get field from document in collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, minimongo

So I have the following publish method that creates a Room with many parameters:

```
Meteor.publish('addRoom', function publishFunction(options, admin, adminKey, members, roomName, isOpen, finalChoice, timeStamp) {
    //add relevant info to collection
    Rooms.insert({
        optionsList: options,
        optionsArr: options.split(','),
        admin: admin,
        adminKey: adminKey,
        membersArr: members,
        roomName: roomName,
        isOpen: isOpen,
        finalChoice: "A choice will be made when the room is closed",
        timeStamp: timeStamp
    });
    return Rooms.find({}, {sort: {timeStamp: -1}});
});
```

This (in theory) should return a cursor to a document with all the information just passed in.

This is my subscribe:

```
var getRoom = Meteor.subscribe('addRoom', options, admin, adminKey, members, roomName, isOpen, finalChoice, timeStamp));
console.log(getRoom.adminKey.toString());
```

I know all those variables that are passed in are defined correctly, however that `console.log(...)` gives me an `undefined` error.

However, `Rooms.find().fetch()` in the chrome's console **does** show the document correctly.

How can I get the admin key of the document correctly?

EDIT:

I should also note that I have `Rooms = new Meteor.Collection('rooms');` at the top of both my sever-side and client-side javascript files.

Comment: You really shouldn't do an `.insert()` inside a publish function. That's going to be unpredictable. You should do that in `Meteor.startup()` or explicitly as a method call.

Comment: @MichelFloyd What would it look like as a method call, and will I be able to accomplish my initial goal that way?

Comment: `Meteor.subscribe` returns a subscription object, not the actual collection. Your `getRoom` variable doesn't have an `adminKey` field. You can get them using `Rooms.findOne`. Please check out the Meteor tutorial about subscriptions: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/collections